# How to pick specific tag values in XML data

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

In my application I need to create a folder structure like "**C:\Laptop1\folder\" , "C:\Laptop2\folder**" on my local machine using the xml file provided. Now the XML file has the file names that I am after.

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Proj>
<MachineIP>
<Machine>
<Name>Laptop 1</Name>
<Path>C:\ZipFiles\Laptop1\folder\</Path>
</Machine>
<Machine>
<Name>Laptop 2</Name>
<Path>C:\ZipFiles\Laptop2\folder\</Path>
</Machine>
<Machine>
<Name>Laptop 3</Name>
<Path>C:\ZipFiles\Laptop2\folder\</Path>
</Machine>
<Machine>
<Name>Laptop 4</Name>
<Path>C:\ZipFiles\Laptop2\folder\</Path>
</Machine>
<Machine>
<Name>Laptop 5</Name>
<Path>C:\ZipFiles\Laptop2\folder\</Path>
</Machine>
<Machine>
<Name>Laptop 6</Name>
<Path>C:\ZipFiles\Laptop2\folder\</Path>
</Machine>
</MachineIP>
</Proj>
```

All I am interested is to know how to fetch the Machine/**Name**/
So far I am not knowing how to pick a particular tag. Anyone know how to pick each Name within the Machine Tag. I have a 300mb file to filter out.

My approach is to fetch each Name within the Machine tag and store it in a string, later use the string to create the structure. But I am stuck please help...

My source code so far:

```
//doc created
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();


//loading file:
filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath + "\\", "MyConfig.xml");
try
{
     doc.Load(filePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Config File Missing: " + ex.Message, "Config File Error",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    Application.Exit();
}

//fetch data:
String[] MachineName = XMLData("PROJ/MachineIP/Machine", "Name");
String[] MachinePath = XMLData("PROJ/MachineIP/Machine", "Path");

//function XMLData():

string[] temp;
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes(MainNode);
int i = 0;
temp = new string[nodeList.Count];
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
     temp.SetValue(node.SelectSingleNode(SubNode).InnerText, i);
     i++;
}
return temp;
```

Thanks,
HRG

Comment: So far I am using XMLDocument, but I am finding it difficult to fetch each tag, there are many...

Answer (score 1):

If you've got enough memory to load the whole file in one go, I'd just use LINQ to XML:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var names = document.Root
                    .Element("MachineIP")
                    .Elements("Machine")
                    .Elements("Name")
                    .Select(x => (string) x)
                    .ToList();
```

If you *don't* have enough memory, you'll need to use `XmlReader` to stream through the input - although you can create an `XElement` from each `Machine` element to work with that. (There are various pages around the net around how to do that, including [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387035.aspx). The code isn't quite how I'd write it, but the general idea is there.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will go thrugh the link u passed over, Is there a way to do it using XMLDocument and XmlNodeList???

Comment: @hrg: Sure - but LINQ to XML makes life simpler IMO. Why would you want to use `XmlDocument`?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read them into 2 array's... here is my code below...

```
//doc created
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
//loading file:
filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath + "\\", "MyConfig.xml");
try
{
     doc.Load(filePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Config File Missing: " + ex.Message, "Config File Error",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    Application.Exit();
}

//fetch data:
String[] MachineName = XMLData("PROJ/MachineIP/Machine", "Name");
String[] MachinePath = XMLData("PROJ/MachineIP/Machine", "Path");
```